# Circuit Playground Express uploading issues

Tags: python, arduino

I have an issue when I try to upload code using the Arduino IDE to my CPE. I have circuitpython 3.0.0 installed and I tried to upload the blink sketch to my CPE it threw this error.

```
No device found on COM11
Set binary mode
readWord(addr=0)=0x30455342
readWord(addr=0xe000ed00)=0x2c303437
readWord(addr=0x400e0740)=0x55002334
version()=SBS00000,4#
chipId=0x55002334
Unsupported processor
Send auto-baud
Set binary mode
readWord(addr=0)=0x342c3034
readWord(addr=0xe000ed00)=0x53550023
readWord(addr=0x400e0740)=0x30455342
version()=740,4#
chipId=0x30455342
Unsupported ARM7TDMI architecture
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

I have tried everything I can and would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: I know that at least the first error it throws means that your arduino is not connected to the port COM 11 and it could be connected to another port such as COM 3

Comment: My board is connected to com 11 and it has com 11 selected too when i run the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[Troubleshooting guide](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-circuit-playground-express/troubleshooting-2)

Turns out it was a Windows driver issue and i had to uninstall it.